# $.focus() not firing in JQuery 1.9.1?

Tags: jquery

$('#id').focus() does not seem to be firing in JQuery 1.9.1.

This fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/qnLVR/12/) works in previous versions of JQuery but breaks in 1.9.1. You can see this by changing the JQuery version in JSFiddle and rerunning the script.

Manually focusing the input will trigger the event, but calling the .focus() does not. Any idea why is this happening?

This is my markup:

```
<input type="text" id="inp"> </input>
<button id='button'>Is Focused?</button>
```

This is my javascript:

```
var focused = false;

$('#inp').focus(function() {
  focused = 'true';  
})

$('#inp').focus();
$('#button').click(function() {alert(focused)});
```

I'm using Firefox, it does appear to work in Chrome/IE9

Comment: The alert says true for me in Chrome using 1.9.1.

Comment: what browser are you using?, works for me in Chrome

Comment: Your fiddle works fine in Chrome.  Which browser are you testing in?

Comment: works in firefox aswell

Comment: Reproduced in Firefox 19.0.2. Writing `$("#inp").focus().trigger("focus");` fixes the problem, but will of course trigger the event twice in other browsers. Looks like a bug indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into this bug: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13363

If you're triggering the event just to make the handlers run, use `$('#inp').triggerHandler("focus")` instead.